# How to pass data to a JQuery script

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html

I bought a pre-built HTML template online and I am trying to customize it so it can speak to my backend python app.

The HTML template has a pre-built static bar chart. By static I mean that the values of the bar chart are hard coded (25, 50, 100) into the JQuery code. I want to be able to replace these hard coded values with variables (x, y, z) so I can have my backend python app send data to be displayed in the chart instead of the hard coded values.

This is the JQuery code in the pre-built HTML template that displays the chart:

```
!function($) {
    "use strict";
    var ChartJs = function() {};
            #some code
            data: [25, 50, 100] # THESE ARE THE HARD CODED VALUES 
}(window.jQuery),

//initializing
function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.ChartJs.init(data_1)
}(window.jQuery);
```

Here is the code in HTML that activates the JQuery:

```
<div>
  <canvas id="bar" height="300" class="m-t-10"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here is my backend python code:

```py
@app.route('/')
def some_function ():

    #some code
    x = 200
    y = 300
    z = 400

    return render_template ('some URL', x=x, y=y, z=z)
```

Id like to be able to send the values of x, y and z from python code to replace the hard coded values of 25, 50, 100 in JQuery.

Can anyone help guide me in the right direction. I am good with python but don't know JQuery.

Comment: Is the jQuery in `<script>` tags, or in a different file?

Comment: Flask use jinja2 template engine. It allow you to use varibale inside html and js file like this {{ var_name }}.

Comment: @JackBashford, currently the JQuery is in a separate file. But I can easily move it into <script> tags if that can solve the issue.

Comment: @Melogs Yes, if the jQuery is contained within the HTML page, you can use the technique from my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the jQuery code is contained within `<script>` tags in the rendered HTML template, use Flask's inbuilt interpolation technique:

```
data: [{{ x }}, {{ y }}, {{ z }}]
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. What if the JQuery code is in a separate .js file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a python or jquery guy  but I worked a lot with AngularJS and Java. I recommend to study a little how REST API's work.

As an example you have an API link on your back-end that your front-end will call like ex. `/getChartData`. This will return your data in JSON format.

More info:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

https://searchmicroservices.techtarget.com/definition/RESTful-API

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: While this may be one solution... One does not "_have to have an API link on your back-end..._". The OP is using Flask templates. It is possible (depending on Jack Bashford's question) to pass the data into the template on the server as part of the rendered page.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes, that's what I was querying - you can just use the Flask interpolation `{{ x }}` in the script.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes, your solution it's much better but I still recommend for the OP to study REST API's a little... can't hurt him.

Comment: @Asp1re - I agree with you. I've removed my downvote since your edit is now a recommendation. Recommendations are different than absolutes. This is a good recommendation - although it doesn't really address the OP's intent in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data always just 3 values? If that's the case, you can pass in variables as arguments like this:

```
!function($) {
    "use strict";
    var ChartJs = function(x, y, z) {};
            #some code
            data: [x, y, z] # THESE ARE THE HARD CODED VALUES 
}(window.jQuery),
```

...
then when you call the function, pass in the variables from python (in PHP, you would use echo)

```
ChartJs(<?php echo $x . "," . $y . "," . $z; ?>);
```